# Split number (ID only) from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split "Sachin Tendulkar (123456)" to

```
Name = "Sachin Tendulkar"    
ID  = "123456"
```

In few cases, I have "320Gangadar Block(MD)(122435)"

I need to split the numbers inside () braces and Name separately,
I have tried `.split(/(\d+)/)`, it is failing in "320Gangadar Block(MD)(122435)"

Expected result:

```
Name = "320Gangadar Block(MD)"
ID = "122435"
```

Comment: Don't split? Try using `match` instead?

Comment: Don't forget that you need to escape `()` in a regexp to match them literally.

Comment: `Name.match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1]` will give you the ID

Comment: `'320Gangadar Block(MD)(122435)'.match(/^(.*)\((\d+)\)$/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the lastIndexOf function on your string, like so:

```js
const str = "320Gangadar Block(MD)(122435)";
const idStart = str.lastIndexOf("(");
const name = str.substring(0, idStart);
const id = str.substring(idStart + 1, str.length - 1);

document.getElementById("name").innerText = "Name: " + name;
document.getElementById("id").innerText = "ID: " + id;
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="id"></div>
```

You don't really need Regular Expressions in this case, they are slower than native JS solutions.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but may you keep your welcomes to comments? Also consider converting your code block to a "stack snippet".

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've edited my answer, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm assuming the downvote was a disagreement with the actual answer, not the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In regular expression there are some reserved characters which have special meaning. `()` are one of those. To use `(` or `)` or any other special character you use escape it using `\`

You can `id` using `string.prototype.match`. You need to match every word inside `()`
For that the regex will be

```
/\(\d+\)/
```

Use slice to remove the `()` around the number

The use `split()` for same regex an you will get all the letters before the number as `name`.

```js
function split(str){
  let [id] = str.match(/\(\d+\)/)
  let [name] = str.split(/\(\d+\)/)
  return [name.trim(),id.slice(1, -1)]
}

console.log(split("Sachin Tendulkar (123456)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regex to retrive the `(id)` then retrive the id from the first text.

```js
function getNameId(text) {

  const regex = /\(\d+\)/g;

  const [id] = text.match(regex);

  const userId = id.slice(1, id.length - 1);

  const name = text.slice(0, text.indexOf(id)).trim();

  return {
    name,
    id: userId
  }


}

console.log(getNameId("Sachin Tendulkar (123456)"))

console.log(getNameId("320Gangadar Block(MD)(122435)"))
```